# a topological mixing example

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **Topologically transitive** or **TT** if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U,V$ in $X$ there exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset$.

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **weak mixing** if $f\times f$ is TT.

and

A continuous map $f:X\to X$ is called **Topological Mixing** if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U,V$ in $X$ there exists $n_0\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset\ \forall\ n\ge n_0$.

We can prove that Topological Mixing $\implies $ Weak mixing $\implies$ TT.
I have a map which is topologically mixing, but I don't know how to show this ?
This is the map :
\begin{align*}
&g : [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1] \\
&g(x)=3((\dfrac{x-1}{3})- \vert x-\dfrac{1}{3} \vert + \vert x - \dfrac{2}{3}\vert )
\end{align*}
Would you mind helping me ?

Comment: $g$ doesn't take values in $[0,1]$. For instance $g(1)=-1$.

Comment: @reza do you still care about this question?

Comment: Yes I do.......